# Proving irreducible polynomial using Eisenstein's criteria.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> How can I prove that using the Eisenstein's criteria, that the polynomial : $x^3 -4x +2$ is irreducible polynomial for prime $2$?

I am new to this topic, and while attempting would try to get the logic of the criteria too.

---

My attempt is : for $x=2$, the value of $a_0 = 2, a_1= -8, a_2 = 0, a_3 =8$.

To apply Eisenstein's criterion there should be a prime $p$ such that

(i) $p\mid a_0, a_1,..., a_{n-1} $ => passes as $2 \mid 2, -8, 0$

(ii) $p \nmid a_n$  => fails as $2 \mid 8$, this also means that the highest term (let, of the power $n$) must be multiplied by a suitable integer multiplier (let, $m$), so that $p \nmid m.p^n$. I am not aware of its algebraic proof, or even its significance, or ramifications; but it is just an observation. It also means that for monic polynomials it must always fail, as $p \mid p^n => p \mid a_n $.

(iii) $p^2 \nmid a_0$ => passes as $4 \nmid 2$, this also means that $c$ term must be non-zero and composite for this condition to be true.

> As given above, the second criteria has failed, so where is the flaw in my attempt?

I have another question, how will one test for any prime fitting in for test, i.e. there must be some restrictions on the choice of primes to be tested. And how it is possible that there is only one value enough for pass/fail.

Comment: Please give reason for down-voting. I made a very serious attempt, and it is nowhere told that lack of knowledge is not appreciated, particularly in the face of attempting to get it. There was no mention of such a simple way to check - online or offline, and so asked rather than sit and mug it.

Comment: I did not downvote this, but I assume that those who did found the question unclear.  Eisenstein directs you to perform a test on the coefficients of the polynomial, not on the values.  You can read about the method and why it works [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion).  I agree that the test is somewhat mysterious on first glance...that's why it gets so much attention.  But the proof that it works is not terribly difficult and is well worth studying.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the link, it is also given below in one of the answers for the "Basic Proof" section. I will try to find the sources also that lead to the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $0$, $4$ and $2$ they are divisible by $2$, but the last coefficient $2$ is not divisible by $4$.

For irreducibility it's enough to use the  Eisenstein's criteria for one prime number.

Comment: I request why, what is the logic for that? Also, will it be enough for failing too. Or do you mean that to clear the test, only one prime is enough, and any number of failure cases of primes are not enough. If so, then please answer my question in the OP..

Comment: In this the Eisenstein's criteria. To check it for some prime number. It's not always works.

Comment: Please elaborate your statement. I am a beginner, and need more details.

Comment: I really don't understand what you did not understand.

Comment: I cannot understand the part: "It's not always works." -- means, in which case it does not work. Will it not work, when even if one prime number, say $2$ in my example passes it, while another suppose $x$ fails it. Or, is that it not possible for any prime ($x$) to fail it, once passed the criteria by another prime, i.e. in my example $2$.

Comment: For example, $x^2+2x+4$ is irreducible above $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I hope your answer summarizes that : "Only one prime is enough to clear the test."

Comment: Yes, of course!

Answer (score 3):

**Your flaw is in the $a_{i}$'s**. These are the **coefficients** of the polynomial, *i.e.* in your case

$$p(x)=a_{3}x^{3}+a_{2}x^{2}+a_{1}x+a_{0}$$

$$\Longrightarrow a_{3}=1,\:a_{2}=0,\:a_{1}=-4,\:a_{0}=2$$

and not the **value** of each monomial evaluated at a specific $x$.

Comment: Thanks, but I feel that there should be some explanation also, as to why only the coefficients $a_j$ are being taken, i.e. no substitution for the value of $x$ is needed.

Comment: @jiten The key here is that a polynomial is an entirely abstract entity. $x$ is not a variable, but an element of the ring $\mathbb{Z}\left[x\right]$. The statement of irreducibility is for the polynomial as an abstract element.

Comment: Thanks for that, but if there were an equivalent statement to the abstract language statement: "an element of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$". If it means that :" the element $x$ is not a variable, but is a particular value taken for arriving at a particular curve given by its substitution". It also means that the polynomial is taken as a parametric equation, and the parameter is not an issue, rather the form of the parametric equation matters, the order, and the coefficients. --- If I am correct, then please state where to find literature that explains in such way.

Comment: @jiten I don't understand what are you getting at. The notion of polynomials as curves is not good when dealing with abstract algebra.

Comment: But, if state to myself the explanation that: "$x$ is an element of the ring $\mathbb {Z}[x]$", then I would try to see the logic too. I request you to elaborate in a simpler context, as I am not aware of the abstract algebra concepts.

Comment: @jiten A **ring** is an algebraic structure you can read about on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics). Just a set with two binary operations that satisfy some axioms. It turns out that the set of polynomials with coefficients from $\mathbb{Z}$ forms a ring with the usual addition and multiplication - this ring is denoted by $\mathbb{Z}\left[x\right]$. Here a polynomial is **defined** as a formal expression: we took $\mathbb{Z}$, added a new object $x$ and **defined** a general element as $$\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_{n}x^{n}$$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}\cup\left\{0\right\}$

Comment: @jiten Any explanation further than this on a polynomial as an abstract entity requires you to learn some abstract algebra first.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not explain why a polynomial is taken as such. I feel taking it as an axiom, would also need some logic. The statement is just a way to state an algebraic fact. Also, for your last comment, I feel that I will learn but to say that AA is an end to itself is not possible, at least to me. My mindset is of viewing AA as a new view to describe that enables "stating" easier, and I feel that it is still based on geometric and algebraic facts. This easier "verbalizing" makes AA a better choice for more complex cases. -- This is my mindset, and have never shared or read before.

Comment: @jiten You could equally ask why a polynomial is a curve. Mathematics is based on axioms, and in the field of rind theory a polynomial is **defined** in this way. The connection between your view of a polynomial as a function and the view of the polynomial as an abstract element can also be established by means of homomorphisms. For now, I think your question is basically about the proof of the theorem. You can see the second proof here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Basic_proof, which requires you to know only elementary properties of numbers.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will follow your advice seriously. But, factually speaking I wanted to learn AA, and had to do number theory to some extent in order to understand it. It is a sort of mesh between the two that I found going through NT first easier.